# Tilting on z-axis android

Tags: android

In Jellybean app listing, or many of the google apps, the indication that you are at the end while scrolling through is if all the items on the screen tilt slightly on the z-axis. How is this accomplished?
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Stock Jellybean doesn't do that. I have seen it on HTC Sense. HTC has their own SDK for Sense. That might have something you can use.

Comment: Actually stock Jellybean does. If you scroll to the end (say left or right) it will start tilting once it realizes there's no more. Also check out Google Play Music. There are some other examples where the entire plane is tilted in Google apps.

Comment: Not on my Nexus 7 it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was looking for something similar when I ran into [this](http://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/kinetic-list-view/). I eventually decided not to use this kind of an effect. But here's hoping it helps you.

Answer (score 6):

It's a view animation - rotation. It can be done with RenderScript or with Android Animation system. Chet Haas and Romain Guy mentioned it here:
http://youtu.be/ToHpumrutXg?t=12m55s

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it could be changeState method in this file:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/android/launcher2/Workspace.java#Workspace.changeState%28com.android.launcher2.Workspace.State%2Cboolean%2Cint%29